# How do you send song metadata to a bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, avplayer

I want to send song metadata (title and artist) to for example a bluetooth car radio.

I've found out you can do something with A2DP/AVRCP, But I couldn't find any examples for iOS.. Just one for android.

I have no clue where to go from here.

Comment: You don't need to worry about Bluetooth specifically.  You need to associate metadata with your playback item. iOS will then deliver that metadata to the playback device, regardless of whether it is a Bluetooth device or an Apple TV or a HomePod. How are you managing playback?  Do you have an `AVPlayerItem`?

Comment: Yes, I do have an AVPlayerItem and I set the title and artist for the “Media Center” with the metadata I receive from an ICY stream.

Comment: @Paulw11 How do you "properly" associate metadata? I got a function that updates my now playing.